# Unity3D Integrating TestRunner/NUnit into build scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine, nunit

I’m currently exploring the possibilities of integrating TestRunner/NUnit into our own build scripts.

The current implementation of "TestRunner" in Unity gives you the option to "run in player", which lets you build and run on a connected device. This is all good, except we have a lot of processing going on in our build steps.

And I can’t really see how to integrate that into the functionality provided by “run in player”?

I need to get access to running the tests and getting the results without using the Unity button in TestRunner.

All the scripts used by TestRunner are "internal" which means I can't add the components in runtime myself.

I don’t understand why the “PlayModeTestsController” is marked as internal, it is basically all you need to get to the test results? Also I can’t seem to figure out how the test run is initialized?

My experiences are from the TestRunner integrated in Unity 5.6, but from the documentation I can't see that it has changed to Unity 2017?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Disclosure: I posted this on the Unity forums as well, but have had no feedback. Link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/integrating-testrunner-into-build-scripts.500920/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest integrating a separate copy of the NUnit library with your project. Then access what you need at command line or elsewhere.

Maybe you can find a way to switch between the two if the built-in Test Runner / NUnit provides things which your own included version of NUnit does not. Obviously, it's fairly important that your NUnit and Unity's NUnit versions match, so the tests you write are compatible between both.

See [this answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1191898/which-version-of-nunit-ships-with-unity-cant-find.html) for versions of NUnit used in different versions of Unity.  Only complaint (and possible feature request) at this stage would be that they don't seem to document current version of NUnit in use per Unity version, and I don't think there is a way to query that at runtime.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, and sorry for the late feedback. The issue with the "play mode" tests in Unity is that they are using their own extensions to NUnit (the [UnityTest] attribute) for running coroutines.
We did a workaround where we basically save the GameObject created by the test runner, and we can then instanciate that when we run our integration tests on a device.